# Cassandra upgrade/repair issues in migration

Tags: upgrade, cassandra

I wanted to migrate part of the column families in a cluster to a new cluster.

I made a snapshot of the source cluster and copied the data, made a new cluster with the same name, same number of nodes that all have the same tokens as their parallel in the original cluster.
I copied the data to the data directory, renamed the file names to match the schema in 1.1 (original cluster is 1.06).

After recreating the schema in the CLI, and upgrading sstables no nodes own any of the data (effective ownership 0.00), any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the original cluster had different DC and rack names in it's topology, I changed the names and copied the data again and it works.